# Python Arguments, Required 1 Argument

Tags: python, arguments

I am working on a zip file password cracker, and I need a brute-force option. I have the basic code for it written out, but I am not sure of how to use an argument to make it work. How can I write an argument to make this work?

```
import optparse
import zipfile
import argparse
from threading import Thread

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-b", "--brute")

def extract_zip(zFile, password):
    try:
        password_encoded = bytes(password.encode('utf-8'))
        zFile.setpassword(password_encoded)
        zFile.testzip()
        print ("[+] Password Found: " + password + '\n')
    except:
        pass

def Main():
        parser = optparse.OptionParser("useage &prog "+\
                        "-f <zipfile> -d <dictionary> / -b <brute force>")

        parser.add_option('-f', dest='zname', type='string',\
                        help='specify zip file')
        parser.add_option('-d', dest='dname', type='string',\
                        help='specify dictionary file')
        parser.add_option('-b', dest='bname', type='string',\
                        help='specify brute force')
        (options, arg) = parser.parse_args()
        if (options.zname == None) | (options.dname == None) | (options.bname == None):
                print (parser.usage)
                exit(0)
        else:
                zname = options.zname
                dname = options.dname
                bname = options.bname

        zFile = zipfile.ZipFile(zname)
        passFile = open(dname)
        brute = open(bname)

        for line in passFile.readlines():
            password = line.strip('\n')
            t = Thread(target=extract_zip, args=(zFile, password))
            t.start()

        if args.brute:
            characters = '1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'
            for length in range(1, int(args.brute)):
                to_attempt = product(characters, repeat=length)
                t = Thread(target=extract_zip, args=(zFile, password))
                t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Why do you think you need an argument? What is the argument? Where does it come from?

Comment: @DYZ I was following a tutorial on YT and he used an argument. He didnt exactly show how to use it so when I run the full code, it says it needs 1 argument

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: If you encountered an error, please include it into your post.

Comment: I see you are using `args.brute` above and `args.brutef` below - are you sure that isn't a typo?

Comment: ... also, just for fun, I suggest timing (say) all three-letter passwords, and then calculate how long it will take to brute-force all 12-letter passwords. You will probably be surprised.

Comment: @HughBothwell I fixed the typo, but it didn't help. @DYZ Here is the error: `zipcracker.py: error: -b option requires 1 argument`

Comment: ... and are you giving it an argument, ie `python zipcracker.py -b 4`?

Comment: I am typing `python zipcracker.py -d locked.zip -b`

Comment: @HughBothwell if I type an argument after it, it gives the help screen, so how do I configure it?

Comment: Um... it looks like you've been playing with the options code a bit. The help string says it wants -f and (one of -d or -b), but it will print usage and exit unless you specify all three (-f and -d and -b). What you want is `if not options.zname or not (options.dname or options.bname)`. Also instead of `args.brute` it looks like you should be using `bname`.

Comment: @HughBothwell so should that fix it? Also how would I get a brute force to work?

Comment: Not quite... it looks like you also probably took out an `if dname` test before opening passFile, and maybe a few other odds and ends. Maybe you should go back to the original code and try figuring out how it works before you change it?

Comment: @HughBothwell That was on purpose so it'll read from the dictionary file if wanted